# How to show/reveal hidden or invisible characters in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, whitespace

How can you show/reveal hidden characters in NetBeans?  In other editors, if this feature is turned on, a space might be shown as a small centered dot, and a tab as a right arrow.  (This feature is useful to see if a file uses tabs or spaces for indentation, among other things.)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This feature was missing for a long time—a [feature request](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4619) was created on November 1999 and it was finally implemented on August 2010 (NetBeans 6.10). You can enable/disable it at "*View → Show Non-printable Characters*".

## Bug history

As of NetBeans 7.0.1, the definition for "non-printable" seems to include tabs and carriage returns but not regular white space char:

[image: NetBeans 7.0.1]

NetBeans 7.1.0 finally displays spaces. However, now it has a new bug where consecutive tabs (or tabs & spaces combinations) collapse into one tab:

[image: NetBeans 7.1.0]

NetBeans 7.4.0 fixes this:

[image: NetBeans 7.4.0]

There're yet a couple of issues:

1. The end of file is represented with the [same symbol as line feeds](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=207285), thus making it non-obvious to determine whether the file ends with EOL.
2. Hidden chars are displayed in the same colour as regular text.

These issues have not been addressed so far but they can be sort of mitigated with the [Editor Whitespace](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52662/editor-whitespace) third-party plugin, which:

- Hides the EOL and EOF markers (which aren't useful anyway).
- Displays other whitespace characters using always the same colour.

Comment: This only shows line breaks for me. No white spaces or tabs! (using 7.0.1)

Comment: And if you change the color of the whitespace, only the whitespace NOT present in comments will reflect this new flavor. Whitespace in comments will have whatever color comments is set to have.

Comment: Also, it doesn't display different whitespaces differently. I was expecting `tab` and `space` to be displayed as tiny arrow and tiny dot respectively, as in `Geany`.

Comment: @mbaitoff - That's a bug I haven't experienced, as you can see from my screenshots. What version are you using?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Sorry, my bad. You use "Show nonprintable characters" mode to display whitespace, while I use "Syntax - Whitespace" coloring mode. In your case, the CR/LF is being displayed, which is not needed, and the display font is distractingly black. In my case, colors are configurable, but the whitespaces are undistinguishable, which is wrong.

Comment: Can you please add a button to the "Customize Toolbars" under View section to be able to drag it on the visible panels?

Comment: This answer has been very well maintained by its poster over time to reflect updates. It is a shame we cannot give more than one vote per person to it. +3

Answer (score 14):

in netbeans 7 you can enable display of spaces, tabs & line feeds like this:

#### spaces

- download font from: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=97902
- install the ttf font
- tools > options > font & colors > Syntax > All Languages > Whitespaces
- choose the installed whitespace font
- more info about the netbeans 6 bug: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4619

#### tabs & line feeds

in netbeans 7 you can enable to see non-printable characters:

- view > show non-printable characters

in netbeans 6 only the spaces part works

Comment: Great tip! Seems to work in linux (Ubuntu 12.04) as well too!

Answer (score 8):

Using Netbeans 8.0.1

View-> Show Non-Printable characters

Comment: same NetBeans  8.2

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 11.10 => Netbeans 7.0.1

The "View → Show Non-printable Characters" mode really not shows whitespaces while font was not installed by me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
View -> Show Non-Printable characters
```

[image]

Comment: Does this add something new to the several existing answers?

Answer (score 2):

Using Netbeans 7.3.1,

View -> Show Non-Printable characters

I can see white-spaces, tabs, and carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has finally been added and is available in NetBeans 6.10. Since this has not been released yet, you can try out 6.10 MileStone 1: http://bits.netbeans.org/netbeans/6.10/m1/. I look forward to the final release!