# Tab/spaces indention issues in IDE's vs vim

Tags: python, netbeans, ide, tabstop

For a python project I am trying an IDE, coming from vim but I have troube how my code is shown resp. indentation. Many lines should be indented because they are inside if-then-else statements.

In SPE and netbeans there are many lines where the indention-space (four) are collapsed.

But I checked the files with tabnanny and pylint and cant see indention problems. ANd the code has been running up to now.

1. How can i check that?
2. Where is the "show whitespace" toggle in netbeans?

Comment: A quick googling reveals that most people that use Netbeans want to switch from spaces to tabs, not the other way around... ergh

Comment: and in 6.9 the show WS feature is not yet implemented.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437913/how-to-show-reveal-hidden-or-invisible-characters-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...Netbeans want to switch from spaces
>   to tabs, not the other way around...
>   ergh – Rafe Kettler Mar 23 at 15:36

I use netbeans meanwhile and like it. 
Yes I converted all spaces to tabs and retab it to 4 in php and python

regards