# Use of undefined constant - assumed ' ' - a blank constant?

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans

The undefined contant error is normally quite helpfull and easy to solve, but I am getting some really weird behavior on both my development and production server (different setups).

My error logs shows tons of errors like this:

```
NOTICE (5): [8] Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' ' (#PATH#/dashboard/tasks.tpl) [61]

NOTICE (5): [8] Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' ' (#PATH#/index/view.tpl) [158]

NOTICE (5): [8] Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' ' (#PATH#/blogs/index.tpl) [51]
```

For me the system trying to define "blank" as a constant?

Often I can solve the error by following the linenumber where their always will be a PHP close tag like this `<?php } ?>` and by first removing the two spaces `<?php}?>` and adding them again I can sometime solve the problem. But new errors keeps popping up.

I use netbeans as IDE.

Here is the full stack trace

```
#0 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/View.php(108): include('#PATH#/d...')
#1 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(835): Zend_View->_run('#PATH#/d...')
#2 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Widget/Abstract.php(292): Zend_View_Abstract->render('application/modules/Blog/widgets...')
#3 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Widget/Abstract.php(258): Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract->renderScript()
#4 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Element/Widget.php(66): Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract->render()
#5 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Element/Abstract.php(583): Engine_Content_Element_Widget->_render()
#6 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Decorator/Children.php(31): Engine_Content_Element_Abstract->render()
#7 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Element/Abstract.php(594): Engine_Content_Decorator_Children->render('')
#8 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Engine/View/Helper/Content.php(78): Engine_Content_Element_Abstract->render()
#9 #PATH#/docs/application/modules/Core/views/scripts/index/index.tpl(10): Engine_View_Helper_Content->renderWidget('blog.list-recent-blogs')
#10 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/View.php(108): include('#PATH#/d...')
#11 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(835): Zend_View->_run('#PATH#/d...')
#12 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(903): Zend_View_Abstract->render('index/index.tpl')
#13 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(924): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('index/index.tpl', )
#14 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(963): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#15 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#16 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(523): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#17 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#18 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Http, Zend_Controller_Response_Http)
#19 #PATH#/docs/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(75): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#20 #PATH#/docs/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
#21 #PATH#/docs/application/index.php(194): Engine_Application->run()
#22 #PATH#/docs/index.php(24): include('#PATH#/d...')
#23 {main}
```

Any suggestions on this behavior would be very much appreciated

### Solution

Thank you for the feedback. By enabling non-printable characters in netbeans (view->non-printable Characters in the menubar) I was able to see the difference.

I copied a "bad" space and a curly bracket and made a search/replace in the total project to solve the problem quickly.

Comment: Note that it's not trying to define a blank constant, but rather one with one space in it.

Comment: Could you post the code of a small **.tpl** file where the problem occurs? (for example on pastebin.com ?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in these lines.
You can ask NetBeans to [display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437913/how-to-show-reveal-hidden-or-invisible-characters-in-netbeans) for you.