# Show control characters in Netbeans 6.5

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible, to show control characters in NetBeans 6.5?
Like carrige return, spaces or tabs etc.
I searched for it in each menupoint but didn't find an option for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show/reveal hidden or invisible characters in NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437913/how-to-show-reveal-hidden-or-invisible-characters-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this version of Netbeans this feature does not exist. The best thing you / I can do is useing the search to find spaces or tabs. Netbeans will mark them.

Answer (score 3):

Check this: **`View -> Show Non-printable Characters`**

Comment: There is not such option only:
Show Editor Toolbar,
Show Line Number,
Show Diff Sidebar,
Show Versioning Label,

Comment: If possible install NetBeans 7.2 instead, maybe this was introduced with a newer version.

Comment: Probably but its a company pc so its not possible :(

Comment: I see ... seems this feature came with NB 7.x. Maybe the workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437913/how-to-show-reveal-hidden-or-invisible-characters-in-netbeans) can help you a bit (next to last post)