# How to remove strange reverse P character at end of line

Tags: netbeans

I've just updated NetBeans to 8.0 and I've experienced that the editor displays a strange/weird reverse P character at the end of each line.

How do I remove it?

Image:

[image]

Comment: Related / possible duplicate - [How to show/reveal hidden or invisible characters in NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437913/how-to-show-reveal-hidden-or-invisible-characters-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please go to 'View' and uncheck the Show Non-Printable objects. That clears off your problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a [CR].

You should be able to remove it with a search and replace. Search for `\r\n` and replace with `\n`. You may need to switch on regexp.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to 'hide' the paragraph sign but show other whitespace I would advice you to install the editor-whitespace plugin (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52662/editor-whitespace).

This approach is very different from [How to remove strange reverse P character at end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425376/how-to-remove-strange-reverse-p-character-at-end-of-line/24027599#24027599) is this solution will hide **all** Non-Printable objects which is not what is asked.

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._