# Showing whitespace/nonprintable characters in Tkinter Textarea (maybe via font)?

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter, whitespace

The program `SciTE` (it's `Scintilla` component, rather) has a very nice feature: You can enable View / Whitespace and View / End of Line, and get a display like this:

[image: test.png]

As you can see, there are dots as spaces, and arrows for the tabs (also `geany` does the same, since it also uses the Scintilla component) - and I'd like to have the same display in a Tkinter textarea.

I tried to look through Scintilla's [src/Editor.cxx](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/scintilla/code/file/ae2518f9b3c9/src/Editor.cxx) because it has a `vs.viewWhitespace` variable, but I cannot see where the code actually handles that case (and how).

Via the question [How to show/reveal hidden or invisible characters in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437913/how-to-show-reveal-hidden-or-invisible-characters-in-netbeans), I found that Netbeans, at least at a certain time, may have used I font [whitespace.ttf](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=97902). If you download and install it, you'll see it only has a dot for a space, and no other glyphs are defined.

So I tried this on my Ubuntu 11.04, with Python 2.7:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- # must specify, else 2.7 chokes even on Unicode in comments

import sys, os

import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as tkMsgBox
import ttk

DEFAULT_TEXT_INP = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu leo leo. Donec felis urna, rhoncus nec ullamcorper bibendum, dapibus ac urna.
  Etiam ut mauris non tellus tristique dictum in ac est. Phasellus feugiat maximus nulla. Donec varius tortor nec orci posuere porttitor.
    Suspendisse rhoncus condimentum bibendum. Cras euismod blandit massa, at ullamcorper ligula malesuada sit amet. Sed sit amet metus arcu.
Aenean quis luctus tellus.
Aliquam ac sem enim.
"""

class GuiContainer:
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.frame = None
  def initBuildWindow(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.geometry("650x450+50+50")
    self.root.title("{0} GUI".format(sys.argv[0]))
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root, name="mframe")
    self.frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    self.tainput = tk.Text(self.frame, wrap=tk.NONE, bd=0, height=17,
                      undo=True, name="tainput"
                      )
    self.tainput.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    self.tainput.config(font="whitespace 11")
    self.tainput.insert(tk.INSERT, DEFAULT_TEXT_INP)
    self.tainput.config(wrap=tk.WORD)

def main():
  guiCO = GuiContainer()
  guiCO.initBuildWindow()
  guiCO.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

... and got:

[image: test2.png]

Clearly, since the "whitespace" font doesn't have any other glyphs, the system "falls through" to whatever font is the default, and fills in the other glyphs from there.

So my questions are:

- Is there a "proper" way to show non-printable/whitespace characters in Tkinter's TextArea? Or if not, any workaround?
- If not, is there a somewhat decent monospaced font for Linux - that also includes both cdots for spaces, and arrows for tabs (and possibly characters for LF) - which I could use to somewhat emulate that "show whitespace" display?

Comment: There is an issue on the CPython tracker for highlighting tabs in Idle.  I currently think the easier thing to do is to color the background.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue22354 for reasons and example code.

Comment: Thanks for that, @TerryJanReedy - feel free to post your comment (i.e. that there are no current facilities for that at the moment), as an answer, and I'll accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, tcl/tk has no built-in method to switch the display of spaces, tabs, and/or newlines.  The most important thing to mark, in most cases, is space added for a tab char.  This is also the hardest for a text widget, like tk.Text, that handles proportional fonts.  Tabs stops are at pixel positions, not 'character' positions.  A background color can be applied to even a pixel wide space.  No character wider than a pixel could be.

Comment: Thanks for this, @TerryJanReedy - good to have it documented; cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I ported the above Tcl script to Python 3.6 and its work all right, except that the substitution character for space (0xb7) prevents word wrapping. I tried adding a zero-width space character (0x200b in the commented-out lines), but tkinker doesn't treat it as an easy break character.

```
    # Display invisible characters space, tab and newline

    text = "\tMary had a little lamb\n\tWhose fleece was white as snow.\n\n"\
    "\nCommands:\t\tCtrl-w toggles the display.\n"\
    "\t\tCtrl-q quits the programme.\n\n"\
    "I ported the above Tcl script to Python 3.6 and its work all right, except that the substitution character for space (0xb7) prevents word wrapping.\n"\
    "I tried adding a zero-width space character (ZWSP - 0x200b in the commented-out lines), but tkinker doesn't treat it as an easy break character."

    from tkinter import *

    class GuiContainer:
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = None
            self.frame = None
            self.showinvis = False
        def initBuildWindow(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.geometry("650x450+50+50")
            self.root.title("{0} GUI".format(sys.argv[0]))
            self.frame = Frame(self.root, name="mframe")
            self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
            self.tainput = Text(self.frame, wrap=WORD, bd=0, height=17, undo=True)
            self.tainput.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
            self.tainput.insert(INSERT, text)
            self.tainput.bind("<Key-space>",lambda event: self.onKeyWhitechar(self.tainput, ' '))
            self.tainput.bind("<Key-Tab>", lambda event: self.onKeyWhitechar(self.tainput,'\t'))
            self.tainput.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.onKeyWhitechar(self.tainput,'\n'))
            self.tainput.bind("<Control-w>", lambda event: self.onShowInvisible())
            self.tainput.bind("<Control-q>", lambda event: self.root.quit())
            self.tainput.focus_force()
            self.tainput.mark_set(INSERT, END)

        def onKeyWhitechar(self, char, event=None):
            convstr = ''
            if self.showinvis:
                if char == ' ':      convstr = '·'      # 0x20 -> 0xb7
                #if char == ' ':      convstr = '·'+chr(0x200b)
                elif char == '\t':   convstr = '»\t'
                elif char == '\n':   convstr = '¶\n'
                self.tainput.insert(INSERT, convstr)
        def convertWhitechars(self):
            if self.showinvis:
                convlst = [[' ','·'], ['\t','»\t'], ['\n','¶\n']]
                #convlst = [[' ','·'+chr(0x200b)], ['\t','»\t'], ['\n','¶\n']]
            else:
                convlst = [['·',' '], ['»\t','\t'], ['¶\n','\n']]
                #convlst = [['·'+chr(0x200b),' '], ['»\t','\t'], ['¶\n','\n']]
            for i in range(len(convlst)):
                res = True
                char = convlst[i][0]; subchar = convlst[i][1]
                while res:
                    res = self.replace(char, subchar)
        def replace(self, char, subchar):
            where = '1.0'; past_subchar = '1.0'
            while where:
                where = self.tainput.search(char, past_subchar, END+'-1c')
                past_subchar= '{}+{}c'.format(where, len(subchar));
                past_char = '{}+{}c'.format(where, len(char));
                if where:
                    self.tainput.delete(where, past_char)
                    self.tainput.insert(where, subchar)
                else:
                    return False
        def onShowInvisible(self):
            self.showinvis = not self.showinvis
            self.convertWhitechars()

    def main():
        guiCO = GuiContainer()
        guiCO.initBuildWindow()
        guiCO.root.mainloop()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently happened to implement this. You can replace the whitespace in the widget as you enter it by handling the Key events for the whitespace input.

```
proc ConvertWhitespace {data showwhitespace} {
    if {$showwhitespace} {
        set data [string map {\u0020 \u00b7 \t \u00bb\t} $data]
    } else {
        set data [string map {\u00b7 \u0020 \u00bb\t \t} $data]
    }
    return $data
}

proc OnKeyWhitespace {textwidget char} {
    global showwhitespace
    if {$showwhitespace} {
        switch -exact -- $char {
            \u0020 {set char \u00b7}
            \u0009 {set char \u00bb\t}
        }
    }
    tk::TextInsert $textwidget $char
}

proc OnShowWhitespace {textwidget app} {
    global showwhitespace
    set data [$textwidget get 1.0 "end - 1c"]
    $textwidget replace 1.0 end [ConvertWhitespace $data $showwhitespace]
}

bind $textwidget <Key-space> {OnKeyWhitespace %W %A; break}
bind $textwidget <Key-Tab> {OnKeyWhitespace %W %A; break}
```

To use this, include a normal `text` widget in the application and use the last two lines to bind `Key-space` and `Key-Tab` to call the special input procedure.   This inserts a center-dot for space and an arrow glyph for tabs plus an actual tab to get the spacing correct. The `OnShowWhitespace` can be hooked up to a checkbutton menu item or some other event to toggle the display of whitespace characters. On loading data or saving to/from file the text from the widget will need to be passed through the `ConvertWhitespace` procedure to fix it if whitespace characters are being displayed visibly.

I did this in Tcl/Tk so the example is in Tcl but it will be relevant to use with Tkinter as well.