# Show non-print characters in NetBeans less vividly

Tags: netbeans, whitespace

NetBeans has an option to [show non-printable characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1437913), but they are shown with the same vividness as printable characters. This means that a space and a dot are very hard to distinguish: the space is slightly raised, but otherwise visually identical. Many other code editors, and even Gedit, will show non-printing characters greyed out. Is there an option to do this in NetBeans, or do I have to file a bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different (and better) solution compared to my other answer, based on feedback from the OP: [download and install the the **Editor Whitespace** plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52662/editor-whitespace).

Its download page shows that it has not been tested for any version of NetBeans more recent than 8.0, but I have checked that it still works with NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 11.2.

To use the plugin:

- Click the **Download** button [on the plugin page](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52662/editor-whitespace) to install the plugin in some arbitrary location.
- In NetBeans: **Tools > Plugins >** select the **Downloaded** tab
- Click the **Add Plugins...** button, navigate to the downloaded plugin, click **Open**, then click **Install**.
- There is no need to restart NetBeans after installing the plugin. Just check the menu option **View > Show Non-printable characters** to immediately see non-printable characters in source code, excluding line break (`¶`) characters.

By default the non-printable characters are shown as black dots, but you can use any other color instead:

- **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Syntax**
- Select *All Languages* from the **Language** drop list, and *Whitespace* from the **Category** list. You can select a specific language form the drop list if you prefer.
- Using the **Foreground** drop list, pick the color you want to use to show the dots representing non-printable spaces.
- Select **Custom...** to create your own color if you don't like any of the standard options.

The only benefit to using the plugin is that it suppresses the display of line break (newline) characters, but that is definitely worthwhile.  If you have a specific requirement to be able to see line break characters, don't install this plugin, and just use standard NetBeans functionality [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641580/2985643).

Comment: It doesn't *only* suppress linebreaks. Without it, spaces within comments were showing as the colour of comments for me, even though the foreground colour was not set to "inherit".

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font color of whitespace characters to any color you want, either for a specific language, or for all languages. Here's how to do it for Java on NetBeans 9:

- **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Syntax**
- Select *Java* from the **Language** drop list, and *Whitespace* from the **Category** list.
- Using the **Foreground** drop list, pick the color you want to use to show the dots representing non-printable spaces. Select **Custom...** to create your own color if you don't like any of the standard options. As you scroll through the options for **Foreground** the color of the dots representing printable spaces in the **Preview** screen change.
- Here's a shot showing the color being changed to magenta:

  [image: nonPrintable]

Notes:

- The approach described above does not change the color of the line break character at the end of each line, and I don't think that is possible. That is arguably a bug, and at least a missing feature.
- Although you can change the **Foreground** color at any time, it is only relevant when  **View -> Show Non-printable Characters** is checked. Checking that option is also necessary to see the whitespace characters in the **Preview** screen.
- The **Background** color for *Whitespace* can also be modified, but the result is invariably ugly and unhelpful.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a Whitespace option, but setting it for "All Languages" works. Thanks. I made it pink.

Comment: The addition of the Editor Whitespace plugin is a big help here.

Comment: @TRiG You are right! I didn't know about that plugin, but it still works and is a better approach for most users, so I posted a second answer. Hiding those newline characters definitely makes the source code easier on the eye.